What is more important upholding justice or protecting interest of few people?
To begin with let me give some background of myself. I am a student of an open university in India (distance education) and at the same time a student of another university (regular course). The regular university of which I am a student is situated in the state of Uttar Pradesh.
The regulatory body for higher education is UGC (University Grants Commission). The UGC has power to declare a university 'fake' in case if it was found violating guidelines of UGC. If UGC declare a university as fake than all degrees awarded by it would become null and void.
The regular university in which I study, violate these norms in the worst possible way:

Students need not to come to colleges during their course of study. In my three years of college I haven't gone there for even one day.
Students only have to appear for the examination at the university (not at the college). Once a person behind me sent his brother to appear for exam.
You just need to fill up the notebook given to you for solving question paper. You can write anything you want.
Even after doing (3) you would get 8 CGPA ~ 70% marks
Instead of doing practicals, you just need to deposit a sum to get marks.

These degree are used by students to apply for various government examination. So that they can prepare for examination instead of studying their bachelor programme stuff.
Now begin the problem. I don't know much about the university but the two colleges affiliated to it don't require you to visit colleges. But university is involved in these malpractices as the exam sheets are checked by university and money is collected by them.
I am just fed up with this. The youth who appear for examination doesn't deserve to sit in class let alone being awarded with a degree. As they misbehave with invigilators all the time. Hence, I want to complain to UGC regarding this.
If I don't complaint about this to UGC this violation of law would continue and more and more students who don't deserve a degree would get it. This would violate the principle of justice and consequentially would lead to unfair competition.
If I make a complaint to UGC and they took any action then the following issues would arise:
A. There are some students at the university who genuinely study. If UGC take any action then their future would be severely affected.
B. Some of those students who acquire degree from these unfair practices are from low income groups and if UGC take any action then their future would also be severely affected.
C. Someone I know well, work in the University, her employment is also at risk if I do something.
However, any action by UGC wouldn't affect me as I have a degree from an open university which is at par with degree of regular degree.
I cannot decide what to do in such a situation. Should I uphold the justice or should I see well being of those few people?

I think it's better to place your post at academia stackexchange: https://academia.stackexchange.com/

@JoWehler Thank you but this post is about a moral dilemma. I think this has nothing to do with academia. The post involves question about ethics and what is right and what is wrong.

I agree with @JoWehler. Observe that almost every paragraph has UGC, GPA etc. Some academia related term that has nothing to do with philosophy

@JoWehler: The description may be academic; but the implication is not.

I’m voting to close this question because belongs on StackExchange Academia

Your concern for the students who earn their degree is commendable, but think about the many people who will suffer from inept students being certified with a degree they don't deserve. Depending on what degree we are speaking about, if it's engineering or something related to health care people who trust them because they have a degree could even be put in danger or die.

@JD: "Do I have to do anything?", "If so how?" or "Which should I choose to overcome my sad situation?" This dilemma has to do with ethics and justice ... not academics.

@SonOfThought Yes, but the phraseology is not in the abstract.

Yours may not be the only such institution covered by the UGC. It is better to report the situation to the UGC in detail directly or indirectly. You should also earnestly request them to save the poor students.  If there are 'humans' in the UGC, a stern and moral decision will surely be taken against such institutions.  Otherwise it can be believed that there are many products of such institutions frolicking in the UGC as well. I think subject philosophy (IMHO) is useless if it cannot analyze and solve a dilemma like this happening here in our life.

Should I uphold the justice or should I see well being of those few
people?

If the situation continues like this, the effects of the products of such institutions on the society can  be imagined. Also, don't forget what happens to the poor few if the intruders get more chance in competitions.
If no one talks about it, even indirectly, injustice will continue to exist in the society for many more years.
Since this yours is not a temporary crisis, you must uphold justice as you are well aware of the situation.  Even the UGC will not act without clues or evidence. Sometimes all the problems can be due to slight carelessness in framing the rules and regulations of UGC.
So giving hints to the UGC is the least thing you can do to get out of this dilemma. When there is pressure on the UGC to do their moral duty it will definitely help future generations. Otherwise they will continue to perform their duties without proper and timely evaluation.  Without cursing the present system, like a little push given to a vehicle with self starting trouble, one’s simple moral duty done PERFECTLY from the lower-level can light up / evoke moral duties of higher-level. [I also had a happy (and great) experience of being directly informed about the program of the Supreme Authority which was affecting a wider region ... eventually the country itself.  It certainly evoked their duties.]
You can also compare with the events in NTA. What would have happened if no one had complained about the conduct of the examination?  At least one thing can be sure that great precautions would be taken the next time while conducting National Exams.
What happens to educational institutions if they are not properly assessed, including building fitness?  A clear proof of this is yesterday's tragedy at the IAS coaching centre in Delhi.  Many problems as you mentioned are easy to ignore; but the wise foresee the consequences and act wisely.

Others have not addressed your enquiry about the potential effects of reporting such unethical universities:

A. There are some students at the university who genuinely study. If UGC take any action then their future would be severely affected.

Remember that any such students who genuinely wish to uphold integrity would actually be satisfied to see this university's horrible malpractice dealt with. Yes, they may feel sad about having some inconvenience due to the repercussions that they may not deserve, but they would be also happy that dishonesty would be decreased. Also, I would question whether their future would be severely affected. It is possible, but it is also possible that they would find an even better path, since after all they are hardworking.

B. Some of those students who acquire degree from these unfair practices are from low income groups and if UGC take any action then their future would also be severely affected.

People who acquire fake degrees that they do not deserve do not have the right to expect a good future, unless they have no choice but to partake in such dishonesty to save their lives or their families' lives. There are very few people who fall into the latter category.

C. Someone I know well, work in the University, her employment is also at risk if I do something.

If she is a good person, this concern is similar to (A), and the answer is the same. There will always be risk in any action, even if it is a good one. We try to mitigate risks to good people, but we cannot just do nothing if the benefit of taking action far outweighs the risks.
